# Does secure flag true makes sense here for https application?

Tags: java, security, web-applications, https

My application is on SSL(https). If user tries to the url with http , webserver(weblogic) redirects automatically to https.
With secure flag true, cookies will be passed on site is accessed with https.

Will adding secure flag as true makes sense here as my site is not entertaining http request and internally redirecting it to https ?

As per mine understanding , whether i add secure flag true does not make any difference as even i access the site with http cookies not be passed.
It will be passes only when my webserver redirecting to https. So i do not see any vulnerability even without adding this configuration.
Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

What if your user accesses via HTTPS, gets the cookies, and then later mistakenly accesses via HTTP? The cookies will get sent from browser to server in the clear, the server will redirect, and then everything will be secure again... but that cleartext transmission? That's why you want to mark them as secure.

Comment: even if user access the site http mistakenly cookies are not sent from browser to server. I had similar question in my mind so i tried exactly the same scenario on firefox as browser and tomcat as webserver and found jsessionId(which travels as part of cookie)  for http was different than https?

Comment: @user3198603 If the cookie do not have the secure flag, it is send from browser to sever to http and https request (the browser can't know if the http answer will be a redirect). So authentication cookies MUST use the secure flag (and the httpOnly flag to be protected against xss)

Comment: Thanks Tom.As i said first i hit the request with https(say jsessionId was 100). Now i hit the same request with http (jsessionId=100 was not passed). So thats why my understanding is when there is a change in protocol(https to http or vice versa), same cookies are not passed. So i want to clear this doubt ?

Comment: For security purposes, in the scenario you just described, when you access via https, the jsessionid cookie is set using the very same “secure” attribute we have been advising you use. That’s why it's not passed. Still don’t believe me? Try it with a different cookie that you have full control over.